# TypeScript: Add custom type to a single property in object

Tags: typescript, object, types, properties, union-types

Let's say there is an object that looks like this:

```
const object = {
  prop: "prop",
  typedProp: "type-1",
};
```

I want the `typedProp` property to only accept the following values: `"type-1"`, `"type-2"`, `"type-3"`. To do this, I created a custom `type` that looks like this:

```
type CustomProp = "type-1" | "type-2" | "type-3";
```

I know that I can assign this `type` like so:

```
const object: {
  prop: string;
  typedProp: CustomProp; // <-- Adding type here
} = {
  prop: "prop",
  typedProp: "type-1",
};
```

My question is, is there a way to assign this `type` directly to `typedProp` (within the object) so that I can avoid adding the `type` to the whole object? I tried to implement it this way:

```
const object = {
  prop: "prop",
  typedProp: "type-1" as CustomProp,
};
```

but it doesn't work as expected, because with this approach, I can add any `string` to `typedProp`, which is not what I would like to achieve. Could you please advise if there is a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want the compiler to think of `object` as type `{prop: string, typedProp: "type-1"}` or `{prop: string, typedProp: CustomProp}`?   It looks like the latter, but sometimes people want the former.  Anyway, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wERX3N) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, Yes, the second one where `typedProp: CustomProp`. Your approach seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Could you please elaborate a little bit more on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a "safe upcast" operator, or a "widening-only [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)".  TypeScript doesn't have direct support for such a thing. There's long been discussion of (and possibly soon there will be an implementation of) the so-called `satisfies` operator, the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) and now [microsoft/TypeScript#47920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920), which some people want for reasons like this, although it looks like the "safe upcast" part won't be supported.  So for the foreseeable future there's not going to be syntax that does this for you.

Luckily you can emulate this with a helper function.

The function `const customProp = (t: CustomProp) => t` will only accept a `CustomProp` input, and will return its input with the type `CustomProp`.  There won't be any widening to `string` or narrowing to just the single `"type-1"` string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types):

```
const customProp: (t: CustomProp) => t;

const badObject = {
  prop: "prop",
  typedPop: customProp("oopsie-doodle") // error! 
}

const object = {
  prop: "prop",
  typedProp: customProp("type-1"), // okay
};

object.typedProp = "type-2"; // okay
```

If you find yourself doing this sort of thing often, you can write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) version of this function that accepts a value of manually specified type `T` and returns that value with a non-widened non-narrowed type `T`:

```
const safeUpcast = <T,>(t: T) => t;
```

And then the `customProp` function is just a special case of `safeUpcast` [instantiated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) with `T` being `CustomProp`:

```
const customProp = safeUpcast<CustomProp>;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYAUBOyxQLxQBEokAtAIyFQA+RJEpATFbceAwMyEDcAUAMbIAdkigIAhgDMIAVTD9xoggB4AKgBoAfAApgALiiqAlPk1RgfAcNH9EKDNlwEJ0uQqTL4SNFhya+APQBUIIiwCF2Po4GugZe9r5gJnhmFrxWYVAARuIAJgDyWQBWEPzhBADevFBQYNFEdTiE6tXm7LnoOAa23g442oTIOAgAlgy5Q7kANhCEJkFQEJjYmACEvAC+6aGiyMWl5VBVNY1gBoSnza30HfU9CY4D9BRz6lALyADW4iCblnslMoAOhuiXwdHYTB472CXx+6SAA)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using TS "Enums",

Define your custom prop as follows,

```
enum CustomProp {
  type1 = "type-1",
  type2 = "type-2",
  type3 = "type-3"
}
```

And then use it as follows,

```
const object = {
  prop: "prop",
  typedProp: CustomProp.type1,
};
```

W3Schools Guide: https://www.w3schools.com/typescript/typescript_enums.php